# Release Template for GitHub

Tags: github

Is there a way to add a `.github/release_template.md` similar to pull requests, so that when you are drafting a new release, it uses the template?

I've seen https://github.com/apps/release-drafter and alike that you can add to your GitHub, but was wondering if this is natively supported.

Comment: So sad it's not available. At least [hub release create](https://hub.github.com/hub-release.1.html) opens a text editor and can read from a file.. ‍♂️

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Templates are [only supported for issues and pull requests](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-issue-and-pull-request-templates).

**Edit:** [Edwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69980071/354577) is neat, but I don't think it does what OP was asking for. I'll leave this answer in place for now.

Answer (score 14):

As of October 2021, you can now add a `.github/release.yml` file to do some autopopulation of the release notes:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/automatically-generated-release-notes#configuring-automatically-generated-release-notes

Right now it is a bit limited, and needs a bit of extra functionality to become a full template, but I think moving forward that will be the file you'd be looking for in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite what you (and I) want but you can use query parameters to pre-populate the create release form:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/automation-for-release-forms-with-query-parameters

which may be useful if for example you add a "Create Release" link in your documentation.
The same approach could be used to create a "custom tab" that uses the link I think (settings > custom tabs)